# Plotting in Table[...]

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I would like to plot a table with functions and their plots. However, something of the type

```
Table[{SomeFunction[x,n],Plot[%,{x,1,2}]},{n,1,3}]
```

seems not to work.

The function $SomeFunction[x,n]$ goes not just through a list but needs to be calculated in some way depending on $n$. Once that is done, I would like the graph next to it.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you are using the Table function incorrectly. Check the documentation of Table to see where your error might be.

Comment: `f(n)` means `Multiply[f,n]`. % refers to the result of the previous top level evaluation, not what you think here.

Comment: f(n) is just notation, not real code.

Comment: So, is there a way to access the result immediately before the plot command? I just want two commands repeatedly executed running through an integer parameter.

Comment: `%` refers to the last output (preceded by an `Out[...]` label), not the result of the last thing followed by a `;`.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. The online documentation is unhelpful as it says there ''% gives the last result generated'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ways to do that:

```
Plot[#, {x, -5, 5},
   PlotLabel -> ToString[#]] & /@ {Sin[x], Cos[x]}
```

or

```
Table[Plot[Evaluate[f[x]], {x, -5, 5}, 
  PlotLabel -> f[x]], {f, {Cos, Tan, Csc}}]
```

or ...

Comment: Thank you. It seem to use that I would have to calculate a list of functions first and then the graphs.

Comment: No... merely *specify* the functions ahead of time.  They'll be calculated with the call to `Plot`.

Comment: I understand that if you mean by calculated the calculation of the function values for the plot. The functions are not specified beforehand, they need to be calculated themselves, for instance taking an integral or something.

Comment: They MUST be specified beforehand (as your example shows), where there is a parameter `n`.  For example:  `f[x_,n_] := Integrate[y^n, {y, 0, x}]` and `Plot[#, {x, 0, 10}] & /@ {Sin[x], f[x,4]}`.

Comment: Okay, maybe what I want to do does not work then. Thanks.